# Representing a graph with an unknown number of nodes?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, graph

For the last few days I cannot think about how to represent a given graph in a text file into an adjacency matrix without knowing the number of vertices in the graph beforehand.

The input file has vertices defined as Strings and a pair of consecutive lines representing an edge between both vertices. For example:

```
VertexA
VertexB
VertexC
VertexD
```

There is an edge from VertexA -> VertexB and VertexC -> VertexD in the above example. Directed, weights are arbitrarily 1.

I would like to implement this in it's own class **which doesn't parse the file directly and instead has only a method** which adds a directed between a given source and destination vertex. For example:

```
// adds a directed edge from vertex1 -> vertex2
addEdgeBetweenVertices(String vertex1, String vertex2);
```

In this method so far I have made a HashMap and if either vertex is not in the map, add it with it's own unique index. (The key being the name of the vertex and the value being its index.)

How can I construct this adjacency matrix using such a method, while maintaining this edge information, but without knowing the number of vertices ( |V| ) prior?

I was thinking an ArrayList of ArrayLists but I can't wrap my head around this.

Comment: Instead of having an index as the value of the map with the vertice names and managing an array in parallel, you could just create a map which has a list or set of vertice names as value (one entry for each reachable vertice).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ArrayList of ArrayList` and your idea is perfect that you can map the `String`s with unique `Integer` ids and then directly add the corresponding vertex to the list.

The problem with `Adjacency Matrix` is that you need to know the maximum limit of the vertexes. `Adjacency Matrix` is not `memory efficient` and also not feasible for dynamic operations. So here `Adjacency List` comes into the picture. I have written a small code to demonstrate the creation of Adjacency List and also how to add new `Vertex` or and `Edge`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class AdjacencyListDemo {

    static int availableId=0;                            //Represents the available id for mapping
    static HashMap<String,Integer> mapping;              //To store the String-Integer mapping for Vertexes
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> adjacencyList;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        adjacencyList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        mapping  = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

        String sampleVertexes[] = {"Vertex1","Vertex2","Vertex3","Vertex4"};

        for(String vertex : sampleVertexes)
            addNewVertex(vertex);

        addEdgeBetween("Vertex1","Vertex2");
        addEdgeBetween("Vertex3","Vertex4");

        System.out.println("Old List: ");
        printList();

        //Add New Vertex if required
        addNewVertex("Vertex5");

        addEdgeBetween("Vertex5","Vertex1");
        addEdgeBetween("Vertex2","Vertex1");
        addEdgeBetween("Vertex3","Vertex2");
        addEdgeBetween("Vertex5","Vertex2");

        System.out.println("\n\nNew List: ");
        printList();

    }

    private static void printList()
    {
        for(String vertex : mapping.keySet()) {
            int index = mapping.get(vertex);
            System.out.println(vertex+" ID: "+index+" List: "+adjacencyList.get(index));
        }
    }
    private static void addEdgeBetween(String vertex1, String vertex2) {
        //get both indexes
        int index1 = mapping.get(vertex1);
        int index2 = mapping.get(vertex2);

        //add index2 into the arraylist of index1 
        adjacencyList.get(index1).add(index2);
    }

    private static void addNewVertex(String vertex) {

        if(!mapping.containsKey(vertex))
        {  
            //assign available ID
            mapping.put(vertex,availableId);
            availableId++;                                   //make increment in available id
            adjacencyList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());     //Add an Empty ArrayList
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

```
Old List: 
Vertex2 ID: 1 List: []
Vertex3 ID: 2 List: [3]
Vertex1 ID: 0 List: [1]
Vertex4 ID: 3 List: []


New List: 
Vertex2 ID: 1 List: [0]
Vertex3 ID: 2 List: [3, 1]
Vertex1 ID: 0 List: [1]
Vertex4 ID: 3 List: []
Vertex5 ID: 4 List: [0, 1]
```

Comment: You may wanna use ND4J instead of ArrayLists if you have high dimensionality: http://nd4j.org/

Comment: @FilipMalczak Sorry but I don't know about it. You can add it as an separate answer if you think it is useful for this scenario. :)

Comment: Hi Sanket, thank for the answer! Are you basically saying I cannot use an adjacency matrix because I don't know the total number of vertices (even if I used an arraylist)?

Comment: @jameshelou `ArrayList` grows dynamically. It allows you to add data till the memory is free to store it. So you can use it as a dynamic data structure which doesn't require to know the total size of data initially.

Comment: @Sanket - my answer would be really similiar to this one, though I'd try to replece usage of List<List<...>> with multidimensional array from ND4J. It's not worth distinct answer, just a note that this could speed up your computations.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that both the `Map` and the `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`s can be part or a solution. Use the `Map<String,int>` to obtain the unique `id` for each `vertex` string, as you already described. Then something like this might work (sorry just more or less Java)

```
HashMap<String,Integer> map;
ArrayList< ArrayList<Boolean> > adjacency;

addEdgeBetweenVertices(String vertex1, String vertex2) {
  Integer idx1 = (map.containsValue(vertex1)) ? map.get(vertex1) : map.put(vertex1,getNextIndex());
  Integer idx2 = (map.containsValue(vertex1)) ? map.get(vertex2) : map.put(vertex2,getNextIndex());

  adjacency[idx1].set(idx2,true);
}
```

Comment: Method for accessing data of  `ArrayList` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to use that adjacency matrix after most of calls to `addEdgeBetweenVertices`, then you can add data about your edges to some array. And just before you want to use it call `Build` (or `Rebuild`) member function of your class (you will need to add this one). Which will actually build your adjacency matrix.